# Convert row data into column data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have data that looks like this:
Field   Value

```
0   CRD 146099
1   LegalName   CHUNG, BUCK CHWEE
2   BusName PRINCIPA FINANCIAL ADVISORS
3   URL https://adviserinfo.sec.gov/IAPD/content/ViewF...
4   CRD 170701
5   LegalName   MESSINA AND ASSOCIATES, INC
6   BusName FINANCIAL RESOURCES GROUP
7   URL https://adviserinfo.sec.gov/IAPD/content/ViewF...
8   CRD 133630
9   LegalName   ALAN EDELMAN
10  BusName EDELMAN, ALAN
11  URL https://adviserinfo.sec.gov/IAPD/content/ViewF...
12  CRD 131792
13  LegalName   RESOURCE MANAGEMENT LLC
14  BusName RESOURCE MANAGEMENT LLC
15  URL https://adviserinfo.sec.gov/IAPD/content/ViewF...
```

How can I convert it such that CRD, LegalName, BusName, URL are the columns. I tried using pd.melt but it doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for.

Comment: Using [transpose](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html)?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) for 2 columns first, then create counter `Series` by [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html), create `MultiIndex` by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df[['Field','Value']] = df['Value'].str.split(n=1, expand=True)

groups = df.groupby('Field').cumcount()
df = df.set_index([groups, 'Field'])['Value'].unstack()
print (df)
Field                      BusName     CRD                    LegalName  \
0      PRINCIPA FINANCIAL ADVISORS  146099            CHUNG, BUCK CHWEE   
1        FINANCIAL RESOURCES GROUP  170701  MESSINA AND ASSOCIATES, INC   
2                    EDELMAN, ALAN  133630                 ALAN EDELMAN   
3          RESOURCE MANAGEMENT LLC  131792      RESOURCE MANAGEMENT LLC   

Field                                                URL  
0      https://adviserinfo.sec.gov/IAPD/content/ViewF...  
1      https://adviserinfo.sec.gov/IAPD/content/ViewF...  
2      https://adviserinfo.sec.gov/IAPD/content/ViewF...  
3      https://adviserinfo.sec.gov/IAPD/content/ViewF...
```

Comment: The data is a dataframe. Sorry it didn't get formatted correctly but there are 2 columns. Field and Value. Field has CRD, LegalName, BusName, URL.

Comment: @bloodynri so is necessary swap `Value` and `Field` in first row like `df[['Value','Field']] = df['Field'].str.split(n=1, expand=True)` in first row?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for DataFrame.[transpose](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html)

Comment: transpose converts it into 1 very long row

Comment: I see. Maybe [split] (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) then transpose. Or see the answer from @jezrael